# CSS: squeeze multiple images close to each other

Tags: html, css

** Edit 3:**

Another example of what I try to achive:

```
+--------------------+
|                    |
|  +--++--++--++--+  |
|  |1 ||2 ||3 ||4 |  |
|  |  ||  |+--+|  |  |
|  +--+|  |+--+|  |  |
|  +--+|  ||7 |+--+  |
|  |5 |+--+|  |+--+  |
|  |  |+--+|  ||8 |  |
|  |  ||6 ||  |+--+  |
|  +--+|  |+--+      |
|      +--+          |
|                    |
+--------------------+
```

Code:

```
<body> 8x <img /> </body>
```

CSS:

```
?
```

---

Hello,

I have 3 images in an HTML page which displays like this:
(basically, in code, it's just three `<img />` in a row)

```
+------------------+
|                  |
|  +---++-------+  |
|  |1  ||2      |  |
|  |   ||       |  |
|  +---+|       |  |
|       |       |  |
|       +-------+  |
|  +--+            |
|  |3 |            |
|  |  |            |
|  +--+            |
|                  |
+------------------+
```

But I would like it to show without the vertical gap between 2nd and 3rd one, like:

```
+------------------+
|                  |
|  +---++-------+  |
|  |1  ||2      |  |
|  |   ||       |  |
|  +---+|       |  |
|  +--+ |       |  |
|  |3 | +-------+  |
|  |  |            |
|  +--+            |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
+------------------+
```

How to? Is it somehow possible to do this CSS?

**Edit:**

In other words, I want the 3rd image to touch the 1st one, as there clearly is some space left. But whan the screen is not large enough, the 3rd "reflows" (is this the right word?) to the next line which maintains the height of heighest element from the line above. And I don't want it to maintain the height, I want it to fit closely together..

**Edit 2:**

code:

```
<html><body>
<img /><img /><img />
</body><html>
```

It's really just a few images in a row......

Comment: Yes, try this, set images 1 and 3 to float left, and image 2 to float right.
I'll help you more if that does not work.

Comment: The problem is, in general, there might be more images than 3 so I don't really know which one to float left or right...

Comment: So do you not know until runtime how many images there are, and what the sizes are? If so, what should happen to the fourth image? What if image 3 is wider than image 1?

Comment: Yes, I know the number of images before hand. But I don't know what the  browser width would be... If 3 is wider than 1, it should touch 2, like in the first examle..

Comment: It even might be that the widths are all the same, it's just the height which varies..

Answer (score 1):

You should try Masonry jQuery plugin. Take a look on the plugin page you should see an example of what you want to achieve: http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/

Answer (score 0):

Put images 1 and 3 first in your HTML and add the attribute align="left" to them.

Alternatively, you can use CSS position:absolute and set explicit X,Y coordinates for each one.

Comment: Wow.  I haven't seen `align="left"` since like 2001

Answer (score 0):

Actually it would be easier if you could show some code...
but you can position images like that

```
.image1{
     position:fixed;
     right:20px;
     top:50px;
}

.image2{
   position:fixed;
     right:100px;
     top:50px;
}
```

and experiment with position you acually want accordingly to the size of your images...

or  you could present them as background images like that:

```
.something {
    background-image:url(yourpath.jpg);
    position:fixed;
    top:711px;
        left:10px;
    display:block;
    height:100px;
    width:269px;
}
```

fixed position is not always the best way to go but it may work in your case...

try googling css images and you can find a lot of things...
also this is a good resource: http://www.opera.com/company/education/curriculum/

and this is a really helpful css cookbook [http://www.amazon.com/CSS-Anthology-Essential-Tricks-Hacks/dp/0980576806](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0980576806)

good luck

Comment: `position: absolute;` will probably be less confusing than `position: fixed;`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the images ahead of time, then I don't understand why you need a general solution. jnkrois gave a good answer for a specific case.

If you want a general solution, I would position them all absolute, and use javascript to calculate the location at runtime. Essentially then you're looking for a packing algorithm, which you could find in a variety of places.

Comment: Even if I know the images ahead of time, I don't know browser width so they might reflow. Yes, I could check for browser resize in javascript and then pack the images but it feel a bit unbelievable that it can't be done it pure CSS.